# What's the relation between a fixed point and a root of a function?

Tags: calculus, functions

A fixed point of a function $f$ should be an $x$ in the domain of $f$, such that $f(x) = x$.

On the other hand, a root (or zero) of a function, should be an $x$ in the domain of $f$, where $f(x) = 0$.

Now, my question is: **is there relation between a fixed point and a root of a function?** If yes, which one?

Comment: None, really. ${}$

Comment: The fixed points of a function $f$ are the same as the zeroes of the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$, and conversely, but these are two *different* functions.

Comment: Rinzler: $f(x) = x$ if and only if $f(x) - x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

A fixed point of $f$ is a root of $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and vice versa.

Comment: Easy, $g(x)=0$ iff $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$ iff $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín: I think KyleMiller didn't mean the vice-versa to go this far (that the fixed points of $g$ be the roots of $f$ as well). But in this case you would need to take $g(x) = x - f(x)$ instead.

Comment: @PedroM. Right, my bad. Although is nicer to use $g(x)=x-f(x)$ :)

Answer (score 1):

A fixed point of $f$ is a root of a particular defining function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ along with it inverse function.

Two fixed points on $ y= e^{(x-2)}. $

[image: FixedPoint]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29                      The functions $ y= x^2 -3 x + 4 ;  x = y^2- 3 y + 4 $ have the same fixed points, as mirror images with respect to line $ x=y$.